# how to optimize layout in graphviz to remove unecessary edges intersections (crossings)?

Tags: graph, graphviz, intersection, edges

I am preparing the automaitc documentation of DB relations. The tool is graphviz. Problem I have is that the placement of nodes on the output image is not opptimal and there are many unecessary intersection of edges.
Is there any method to perform optimazation of the graph so the result will have minumum edges intersetction (crossing)?

```
    digraph structs {
      node [shape=Mrecord];
      overlap="false";
      splines="true";
      layout=sfdp;
      rankdir=LR;

      ttype[label="::: ttype :::|<id>id|<table_name>table_name|<type_name>type_name|<synopsis>synopsis"];
      tevents[label="::: tevents :::|<id>id|<id_tcases>id_tcases|<id_ttype>id_ttype|<synopsis>synopsis|<expiredate>expiredate|<open>open"];
      toperationlog[label="::: toperationlog :::|<id>id|<executiondate>executiondate|<executiontime>executiontime|<query>query|<id_tusers>id_tusers"];
      tdocuments[label="::: tdocuments :::|<id>id|<id_tcases>id_tcases|<id_ttype>id_ttype|<path>path|<creationdate>creationdate"];
      tcustomers_cases[label="::: tcustomers_cases :::|<id_tcustomers>id_tcustomers|<id_tcases>id_tcases"];
      tcases[label="::: tcases :::|<id>id|<creationdate>creationdate|<incomingdate>incomingdate|<clousuredate>clousuredate|<synopsis>synopsis|<notes>notes|<id_ttype>id_ttype|<id_tusers>id_tusers"];
      tusers[label="::: tusers :::|<id>id|<username>username|<password>password|<firstname>firstname|<lastname>lastname|<role_id>role_id"];
      tcustomers[label="::: tcustomers :::|<id>id|<firstname>firstname|<lastname>lastname|<email>email|<phone>phone|<mobile>mobile|<address>address"];

      tevents:id_tcases -> tcases:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tevents:id_ttype -> ttype:id [arrowhead="none"];
      toperationlog:id_tusers -> tusers:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tdocuments:id_tcases -> tcases:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tdocuments:id_ttype -> ttype:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tcustomers_cases:id_tcustomers -> tcustomers:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tcustomers_cases:id_tcases -> tcases:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tcases:id_ttype -> ttype:id [arrowhead="none"];
      tcases:id_tusers -> tusers:id [arrowhead="none"];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting [remincross](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3aremincross) to true will cause cross minimization to run a second time, which should improve the look of the graph by reducing the number of edge crosses.

Comment: is there an algorithm to do that ?

Comment: For the record, this is now the [default behavior](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/remincross/) on Graphviz.